# Spring Data JpaRepository throws LazyInitializationException when using method getById() but not when using findById()

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

in my Spring Boot (version 2.5.4) I have a service that executes one of its methods by a `ExecutorService` (in new Thread). in this new Thread I access some of my repositories (`JpaRepository`s). I see different behavior in `JpaRepository`'s `getById()` and `findById()`, I searched but did not found any.

this is my entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class LimoSet {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "_id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "_status")
    private String status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "set", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Limo> limos = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "_statistics")
    private String statistics;

}
```

this is repository:

```
@Repository
public interface LimoSetRepository extends JpaRepository<LimoSet, String> {
}
```

and this is the service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class GeneratorService {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GeneratorService.class);
    private final LimoSetRepository setRepository;
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);;


    public void generate(Options opts) {
        .
        .
        .

        Callable<String> task = () -> {
            try {
                this.runGenerate(opts);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                var set = setRepository.getById(opts.getName());
                set.setStatus(e.getMessage());
                setRepository.save(set);
            }
            return "ok";
        };
        executor.submit(task);
    }

    void runGenerate(Options opts) throws JsonProcessingException {
        .
        .
        .
        var set = setRepository.findById(opts.getName()).get(); //this is ok
        var set = setRepository.getById(opts.getName()); //this throws LazyInitializationException
        set.setStatus("GENERATED"); //the Exception is reported in this line
        setRepository.save(set);
    }
}
```

why `findById()` works but `getById()` does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few factors which sum up to the LazyInitializationException.

For primers:

**get acquainted with the different semantics of `findById` and `getById`**

- `findById` fetches entire object
- `getById` fetches object proxy

See: [How do find and getReference EntityManager methods work when using JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/)

> When loading a Proxy, you need to be aware that a `LazyInitializationException` can be thrown if you try to access the Proxy reference after the EntityManager is closed.

Secondly, you need to understand why `runGenerate` runs with no active transaction, even if the class is marked as @Transactional.
(Note: no active transaction is the root cause of closed EntityManager)

To make sure that the transaction is not active, see [Detecting If a Spring Transaction Is Active](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transaction-active):

```
assertTrue(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
```

**Why parent transaction from the test is not propagated**

- `runGenerate` is run via executor on a separate thread
- active transaction is kept as a thread-local, so transactions do not propagate across threads.

**Why `@Transactional` on `runGenerate` has no effect?**

Spring (by default) uses CGLIB proxies to enable aspects.
CGLIB proxies has 2 requirements:

- the proxied method must be public
- you must call the method via the proxy (not via the actual object)

None of these conditions is met.

**Why the transaction is active in the test itself**

Spring provides a special `TestExecutionListener` called `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`, which checks if the test method is marked as @Transactional, and starts transaction if needed

**How to fix**

- extract `runGenerate` to a service, mark it as public and @Transactional
- autowire the new service into your test
- more generally, take note what parts of your task operate under transactional context (catch block of your task is not transactional)
- also more generally, learn about dirty checking. once you have your methods to run under transactional context, the `save` calls will be redundant.

Comment: thank you for your answer. concerning  "... you need to understand why runGenerate runs with no active transaction", if there is no active transaction why the `findById` works but `getById` does not work? or I am missing something!?

Comment: Under non-transactional method, spring opens entity manager for each query. FindById fetches entire object, after closing EM it becomes detached, but you can use it and re-attach it (via save). The proxy cannot be un-proxied when detached, hence LazyInitializationException

Comment: very clear answer! thank you